# How do I use drop down to sort results

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a 'search box' and a 'sort by' drop down menu. when a user uses the search function I would like the 'sort by' drop down menu to sort the results depending on the drop down they select. Im not sure where to begin, using Javascript.
For Example, search for cars, sort by Price
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Please post your approach - some code would be nice, because nobody here is a freelancer for free.

Comment: There are quite a few JS/jQuery plugins available that do this, and many are free.